# Don't understand how to correct an error within Community Visual Studio 2022 with CommunityToolkit.Mvvm

Tags: .net, maui

I'm learning .NET Maui and using MS Community Visual Studio and I'm following .NET Maui for Beginners created by James Montemagno, Product Manager, Microsoft.  After using the 'Manage NuGet packages and installing CommunityToolkit.Mvvm ver 8.2.2, I have created the following code from the lesson material:

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MauiApp1.ViewModel;

public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    string text;
}
```

I receive the following errors
[Dependencies_net7.0-android_Analyzers_CommunityToolKitMvvm.SourceGenerators](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvwNW.jpg)

Could someone point me in the right direction?
Thank you

I have tried removing the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm and installing an earlier version.

Comment: please do NOT post error messages as images

Comment: What errors or exceptions have you met? Can you help add them as text format to your post?

Comment: I have taken the liberty of reverting the removal of the picture you posted. The reason for this - in this particular cases those are not errors, and the picture gives better clue about what and where you are looking at. If you consider that I did something wrong, you can revert my action, and I promise to not interfere anymore.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code or the MVVM source generators with respect to your code. Don't worry about those messages, they should be irrelevant for you as long as you don't see actual error messages or warnings in the console/output window.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I can replicate the issue when firstly installing the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.Mvvm/) version:`8.2.2`.

If you want to eliminate the errors produced by the SourceGenerators, you can try to install the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.Mvvm/) version:`8.0.0` and then upgrade its version to `8.2.2`, the errors would vanish like below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, When Jason told you that you should not post images of errors, he meant that you should place text instead. I had to look for your "errors" in the edit history.

Second, those are not errors. This what you are looking at is not even a warning.
Plain and simple the toolkit is telling you that it is capable of.

If you want to learn more, you can search about diagnostic analyzers.